# Вопрос по функции высшего порядка JS

Tags: javascript

только начал изучать javascript, дали такую задачку :
Написать функцию, которая принимает число как аргумент и возвращает функцию, которая также принимает число как аргумент и возвращает сумму этих двух чисел. Выведите в консоль результат.

вообще не понимаю формулировку, вот что я попытался сделать, но понимаю, что это не по заданию.

```
function func1 (x) {
    return 2;
};
function sum (func, x) {
  return func(x) + x;
};
console.log(sum(func1, 5));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function sum(x) {
    return function(y) {
        return x + y;
    };
}

let f = sum(5);
console.log( f(0), f(1), f(2) );

console.log( sum(1)(2), sum(2)(2), sum(40)(2) );
```

Comment: обьясните пожалуйста 2 последние строчки

Comment: @GREATkuzya, 1) Функция `sum` вернула некоторое значение, которое мы запомнили в переменной `f`: `let f = sum(5);`. 2) Так как возвращаемое функцией `sum` значение есть не число или строка, а самая настоящая функция, то в переменной `f` хранится функция, и её можно вызвать: `f(0)`, `f(1)`, ... 3) Возвращаемую из `sum` функцию можно вызвать сразу, без сохранения в переменной: `sum(1)(2)`, `sum(2)(2)`, ...

Comment: поясните пожалуйста, почему "function(y)" я могу назвать только так и никак иначе? и каким образом получается в итоге вид "sum(x)(y)", почему не sum(x(y))?

Comment: @GREATkuzya, `почему не sum(x(y))?` Как это по вашему должно выглядеть? `sum(5(1))`, `sum(1(2))` и т.п.?

Comment: я просто не понимаю откуда такой синтаксис, функции вложены одна в другую, аргументы просто в скобках друг за другом. если поясните, буду очень рад. и вот эта внутренняя функция "function(y)", она пишется только так? я в начале приходил к похожему решению, но на этом месте назвал функцию "func2(y)" ну и соответственно ничего не получалось.

Comment: @GREATkuzya, функция — это тоже объект. Её можно создать и вернуть из функции также как и прочие объекты. Вас не удивляет, что можно написать так: `return {"x": 1};`? Здесь `return function(y) {...}` — создаётся объект-функция и тут же возвращается из `sum`. Так как из `sum` мы вернули **функцию**, то её также можно вызвать используя круглые скобки: `sum(1)(2)`. Здесь первые круглые скобки — это вызов `sum`, а вторые круглые скобки — это вызов той функции, которая была создана внутри `sum` и возвращена из `sum`.

Comment: @GREATkuzya, если вам в новинку такой синтаксис, почитайте о каррировании (curring).